# oracle: how can i update or insert

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

i have this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE NUEVO_SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL 
(d_REGIONAL IN SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL.REGIONAL%TYPE, d_NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR IN SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL.NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR%TYPE , d_ESTADO IN SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL.ESTADO%TYPE , d_SOPORTE IN SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL.SOPORTE%TYPE , d_FECHA_CARGUE IN SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL.FECHA_CARGUE%TYPE) 
as 
    resultado number;
    BEGIN
        select id into resultado
        from seguridad_social 
        where ((nombre_trabajador like d_NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR) and (extract(month from fecha_cargue) =  extract(month from to_date(d_FECHA_CARGUE,'dd/mm/yyyy'))) and (extract(year from fecha_cargue) = extract(year from to_date(d_FECHA_CARGUE,'dd/mm/yyyy'))));
    exception
        when no_data_found then
            resultado := -1;
    if(resultado = -1) then
        INSERT into seguridad_social(regional,nombre_trabajador,estado,soporte,fecha_cargue)
        VALUES (d_regional, d_nombre_trabajador, d_estado,d_soporte,d_fecha_cargue);

    else
        update seguridad_social set estado= d_estado, soporte = d_soporte, fecha_cargue = d_fecha_cargue
        where id=resultado;
    end if;
END NUEVO_SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL;
```

thanks to your answers I was able to correct the syntax error but the problem continues that it does not update the existing data but inserts it, check my select and if it returns values

I also tried it this way

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE NUEVO_SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL(d_REGIONAL IN SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL.REGIONAL%TYPE, d_NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR IN SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL.NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR%TYPE , d_ESTADO IN SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL.ESTADO%TYPE , d_SOPORTE IN SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL.SOPORTE%TYPE , d_FECHA_CARGUE IN SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL.FECHA_CARGUE%TYPE)
as
BEGIN
  merge into seguridad_social sg using dual 
  on (sg.nombre_trabajador like d_NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR and extract(month from sg.fecha_cargue) =  extract(month from to_date(d_FECHA_CARGUE,'dd/mm/yyyy')) and extract(year from sg.fecha_cargue) = extract(year from to_date(d_FECHA_CARGUE,'dd/mm/yyyy')))
         when not matched then insert (sg.regional,sg.nombre_trabajador,sg.estado,sg.soporte,sg.fecha_cargue)
           values (d_regional, d_nombre_trabajador, d_estado,d_soporte,d_fecha_cargue)
         when matched then update set
           sg.estado = d_estado, sg.soporte = d_soporte, sg.fecha_cargue = to_date(d_fecha_cargue,'dd/mm/yyyy');
END NUEVO_SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL;
```

but when I called him, he never updated the information, he only inserted it even if it was already there

i need help :c

my table
[image]

Comment: Your first attempt has an extra `end;` - you end the main procedure block twice. In both of them the date handling looks wrong - if `fecha_cargue` is a date then so id `d_feca_cargue`, so you shouldn't be using `to_date()` - your NLS settings might be enough to get wrong results (if it doesn't error); and why are you using `like` for single values, particularly if they are numbers? Including your table definition and sample data might reveal other issues or explain why you aren't getting a match.

Comment: You can only end it once, so remove one of the last two `end` keywords. Next, `resultado` is only declared in the inner block and so will be invalid in the section after it ends. But is your question about tracing compilation errors or is it about implementing a merge?

Comment: ya corregi mi sintaxis del primer codigo pero a la hora de ejecutar nunca me actualiza siempre me inserta como nuevo dato cuando ya habia uno he hice la verificacion de mi selec si retornaba un resultdo y si me retorna

Comment: d_NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR is type varchart

Comment: As `d_fecha_cargue` is a date, `to_date(d_fecha_cargue, 'dd/mm/yyyy')` is wrong and probably messing up the join. Remove the `to_date()` from around it.